# plot igraph in a big area

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Just wondering if it is possible to increase the size of the plot so that the nodes and edges can be more scattered over the plot.

Original plot:

[image]

What are expected:

[image]

I tried many parameters in the layout function such as area, niter, and so on, but all of them do not work. By the way, I am using 'igraph' package in R.

Comment: Where you using one particular layout function? There are a bunch of different ones available if you look at `?layout`.

Comment: it might be due to the first image being a big mess, but your data seems to be highly connected, making such clear plots impossible

Comment: @phonixor Yes, it is a connected component I retrieved from a social network.

Comment: @MrFlick I tried layout.lgl and layout.fruchterman.reingold, which are suggested by the manual document to deal with graph in large size

Comment: If your edges have weights, you might consider thinning your connection to make it less connected and subgroups might become clearer

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to the actual size of the produced output (pdf, png, etc), you can configure it with the **width** and **height** parameters. Check this [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html) for png,bpm, etc, and this [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html) for PDF format.

A MWE is something like this:

```
png("mygraph.png", heigh=400, width=600)
#functions to plot your graph
dev.off()
```

If you are referring to the size of the graphic produced by the layout function, as  @MrFlick referred, you should check the parameters of the particular layout you are using.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In your second graph, it's obviously the graph can be divided into several clusters (or sections). If I understood you correctly, you want to have a layout that separates your clusters more visibly.

Then you can draw this by calculating a two-level layout:
First, calculate the layout of the graph in order to find a place for each cluster.
Second, calculate the layout in each cluster according to first step and plot nodes in the corresponding place.